# Scraping HTML with Rvest: no text

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

I am trying to scrape information from HTML webpages, I have the direct links but cannot for some reason get to the relevant text.

These are two examples of the webpages:

http://151.12.58.148:8080/CPC/CPC.detail.html?A00002
http://151.12.58.148:8080/CPC/CPC.detail.html?A00003

After I read the html, I am left with all the source code aside from the relevant text (which should change from page to page).

For example, the first link gives a page with this:

> data di nascita 1872

which is coded, when I inspect it on my browser, as:

```
<p y:role="datasubset" y:arg="DATA_NASCITA" class="smalltitle">
     <span class="celllabel">data di nascita</span>
&nbsp;
<span y:role="multivaluedcontent" y:arg="DATA_NASCITA">1872</span>
        </p>
```

however, when I read it with my code:

```
link <- 'http://151.12.58.148:8080/CPC/CPC.detail.html?A00002' 
page <- read_html(link)
write.table(as.character(page), "page.txt")
```

and I print "page", to check what I am getting, the same part of the code is:

```
 <p y:role=\"datasubset\" y:arg=\"NASCITA\" class=\"smalltitle\">
     <span class=\"celllabel\">luogo di nascita</span> 
<span y:role=\"multivaluedcontent\" y:arg=\"NASCITA\"></span>
        </p>
```

without 1872, which is the piece of information I am interested in.
(and also without   not sure if that is indicative of anything).

I can't seem to get around it, would anyone have suggestions?
Thank you very much!

Comment: That's because the actual HTML source does not contain the data you want. It's dynamically created on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a bit further, the site's HTML code loads a bunch of javascript and then has a template which is filled in after the document loads and also uses the query parameter as some type of value that get computed. I tried to just read in the target javascript file and parse it with `V8` but there are too many external dependencies.

To read this, you'll need to use something like `splashr` or `seleniumPipes`. I'm partial to the former as I wrote it .

Using either requires running an external program. I will not go into how to install Splash or Selenium in this answer. That's leg work you have to do but `splashr` makes it pretty easy to use Splash if you are comfortable with Docker.

This bit sets up the necessary packages and starts the Splash server (it will auto-download it first if Docker is available on your system:

```
library(rvest)
library(splashr)
library(purrr)

start_splash()
```

This next bit tells Splash to fetch & render the page and then retrieves the page content after javascript has done its work:

```
splash_local %>% 
  splash_response_body(TRUE) %>%
  splash_user_agent(ua_macos_chrome) %>%
  splash_go("http://151.12.58.148:8080/CPC/CPC.detail.html?A00002") %>%
  splash_wait(2) %>% 
  splash_html() -> pg
```

Unfortunately, it's still a mess. They used namespaces and they are fine in XML docs but somewhat problematic the way they've used them here. But we can work around that with some clever XPath:

```
html_nodes(pg, "body") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath=".//*[local-name()='h4' or local-name()='p' or local-name()='span']/text()") %>% 
  html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
  discard(`==`, "")
##  [1] "Abachisti Vittorio"                        "data di nascita"                           "1872"                                     
##  [4] "luogo di nascita"                          "Mirandola, Modena, Emilia Romagna, Italia" "luogo di residenza"                       
##  [7] "Mirandola, Modena, Emilia Romagna, Italia" "colore politico"                           "socialista"                               
## [10] "condizione/mestiere/professione"           "falegname"                                 "annotazioni riportate sul fascicolo"      
## [13] "radiato"                                   "UnitÃ  archivistica"                       "busta"                                    
## [16] "1"                                         "estremi cronologici"                       "1905-1942"                                
## [19] "nel fascicolo Ã¨ presente"                 "scheda biografica"                         "A00002"
```

Do this after you're all done with Splash/`splashr` to remove the running Docker container:

```
killall_splash()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've used Selenium before but I'll look into splash!